# Why can't I compile this program with clang?

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, clang++, llvm-clang

I have downloaded Windows snapshot build from [here](http://llvm.org/builds/). I just run that executable file & Write following simple C++ program

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
     std::cout<<"Welcome to Clang\n";
}
```

**clang++ 999.cpp**

```
999.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

What is going wrong here? What I am missing? What should I do so that I can successfully compile my C & C++ programs on Windows using clang?

Comment: What OS are you using ? Could be a bad install ? Do you have the iostream file somewhere on the system ?

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

There's no windows platform support for clang's C++ standard library:  http://libcxx.llvm.org/

This is why you can' t simply compile this code in windows:  it doesn't find the headers you're referring to.

***Edit:***

Following Tom's remark, you can however give clang a build target:

```
clang -target i686-pc-windows-win32 ....
```

When a win32 target is given, clang will use msvc's library if it's installed, and if the environment variable `INCLUDE` was not set to another location.

Note however that [llvm website](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html#id2) gives a disclaimer about it:

> Clang mostly works on Windows, but does not currently understand all
>   of the Microsoft extensions to C and C++. Because of this, clang
>   cannot parse the C++ standard library included with Visual Studio, nor
>   parts of the Windows Platform SDK. However, most standard C programs
>   do compile.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Visual Studio installed.

Clang uses its libs and headers.

Comment: I imagine that it can. But i suspect that you have to do something to get it work this way: i have msvc installed and tried out clang, but get similar errors as op

Comment: @Christophe: No, against what libraries would you link then...? You have to either choose the Visual Studio target or the MinGW target. Ensure your target is MSVC, check with '-v'.

Comment: @Tom:  with -v it showed that default options look for mingw libraries.  So there are some more stuff to do to get it run, and llvm  gives no guarantee that it will actually work with MSVC's libraries. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Christophe: Clang does indeed work with MSVC libraries, a lot of people are working on it, while nobody really seems to care about the MinGW target anymore. I am watching the llvm-mirror/clang and llvm-mirror/llvm repos on GitHub, and from what I can see, a lot of effort is put into clang to get clang working properly with the MSVC libraries and headers, especially from Google. They want to get rid of MSVC in favor of Clang for Chrome.

See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html for more details.

Comment: @Christophe: I don't know the exact MSVC triple, but you may have luck with something like this:
`clang++ -target i686-pc-win32-msvc <src.cpp> [...]`.

Maybe your clang has been built with MinGW instead of MSVC - which would cause it to target
MinGW by default instead of MSVC.

Comment: thanks for this interesting contribution. I downloaded the precompiled version. The few tests i made on windows with the right target all worked. Due to their disclaimer, i thought it was luck. I understand that it should work more and more. But why do they improve the compiler to work with msvc libs instead of improving libc++ to be more portable ?

Comment: @Christophe: I think it's [already possible to use libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/tree/master/src/support/win32) on Windows - besides the `<thread>` header, which would require a pthreads port. I think a proper libc++ port will follow once Clang and LLD achieve "100%" compatibility on Windows.